# What is the hexadecimal code of the "blue" background color of Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, colors, facebook

I want to color my mobile phone application with a background color like Facebook's blue background color. So what is the hexadecimal code of it ?

Comment: i think there are browser plugins that can compute that number for any king of color

Comment: You may want to try this Chrome extension: WEBSTORE__URL It helped me to change color theme of Facebook UI [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-colorize-fb-beau/knpaaiffobciomoabocebipleenjolnm?hl=en

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The colour of the main blue banner is *#3b5999*, and the lighter blue colour used for the backgrounds of comments is *#eeeff4*. A way to figure this stuff out is grab a screenshot and open it in image editing software that has a colour picker tool (e.g [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/))

Comment: Taking a screen shot often uses a different color profile then you expect depending on how you have things setup. Watch out.

Comment: The main blue color used by Facebook, is quite dull in color. I've noticed people adding a hint bit more color to it, for example, Aol uses `#3b579d` for sharing widgets. Although, as a background, you might be fine with a duller color.

Comment: The one answer marked correct is wrong. See other answers below.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use firebug, for firefox and it can show you the css attached to any element with the inspect tool.

Comment: "Go and take a look yourself". Useful advice, +1.

Comment: While this was useful advice, it does not *actually* answer the question. Note that this is now outdated as Firebug support has been discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

Look at here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorpalettes/ig/Color-Palettes/facebookpalette.htm

Colors are:

```
#0x3b5998
#0x8b9dc3
#0xf7f7f7
#0xdfe3ee
```

Answer (score 3):

the blue color used by facebook:

#3B5998

Answer (score 3):

I know an answer has already been accepted. But for the sakes of other visitors, I believe the best authority on this issue is Facebook!! According to them, the official background colour is #3b5998. I quote here from     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices#buttondesign : "If you use a color, make sure it's the official Facebook blue; 3b5998. Otherwise stick with black and white. Color is one of the best ways for people to recognize something quickly."

Comment: Thank you! I googled hoping to find the official FB documentation, and your answer was the first result that referred to it.

Comment: Looks like they've moved things around, and maybe changed the color value! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience/#buttondesign - "Recommended buttons colors are white and the official Facebook blue; 4267B2"

Answer (score 2):

I found the hex to be `#4267b2` if you want to have the same color as the "like" and "share" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The color of facebook's background is #3b5998;

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021,
According to [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience/#buttondesign) Facebook blue is

- CMYK Coated: 83 / 52 / 00 / 00
- CMYK Uncoated: 77 / 36 / 00 / 00
- PMS 2727C
- PMS 2382U
- Hex #1877F2
- R = 24 G = 119 B = 242