# CSS Layout Trouble

Tags: css, background

I've been trying to build this CSS layout for a while now. I am trying to make this:

http://tinypic.com/r/29xx9ps/6

And I can not even get the first step done of putting the blue bar at the top of the screen. But any help would be much appreciated.

I also found this:

[What is the hexadecimal code of the "blue" background color of Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442123/what-is-the-hexadecimal-code-of-the-blue-background-color-of-Facebook)

give me the color codes but please any help would be appriated I'm watching tutorials like crazy but I have a wired dead line for this

Comment: What have you tried? If you post the code that you have already written, you're much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am oblvious when it comes to css

You may need to learn it then. I recommend you start with http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

> And I can not even get the first step done of putting the blue bar at the top of the screen

Your "Title WHITE" text and "Sign Up" button are inside something: in your HTML, let that "something" be a `<div>` element.

For example if you do "View Source" on my web page at http://www.modeltext.com you'll see that I have a `<div id="HEADER">` element.

My CSS at http://www.modeltext.com/images/styles.css specifies:

```
#HEADER
{ 
  background-image: url(bg_main.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom; }
```

That's because I'm using an image as the background, to get those lines on the background. If instead you want a simple solid background color, then you could simply use the [background-color](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color) property instead.

Comment: Okay bear with me im still a little lost im going try to figure this out.

Comment: @SarahLee The `#HEADER` in the CSS is a "CSS selector" which means, "apply these CSS properties to the element in the HTML which has the `id="HEADER"` attribute. Post again if you have further questions.